# List collection from controller to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

hi i am doing my project in mvc4 using c#

i have list in my controller

```
   public ActionResult Gallery()
    {
        string folderpath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Gallery/GalleryImages");
        List<String> currentimage = new Gallery().GetGalleryName(folderpath);
        return View(currentimage);
    }
```

i want to list the items in currentimage in my view , how it possible, i am trying the following

```
@model List<String>
@foreach(var item in Model)
 {
  <p>
      @item   // what will be write here..
 </p>
 }
```

Comment: you have the right idea. that `should` work! Have you confirmed in debugger that the list is populated?

Comment: thank you , it is worked.. actually problem is somewhere else in my code. thank you for answering me